# How to use custom modules in Twilio Functions?

Tags: node.js, function, twilio, serverless, commonjs

I was looking for a way to simplify and extract some of the code into a custom common.js module to make my Twilio function more readable.

I was expecting the serverless api to take the custom js file automatically and let me require it where I wanted it, but after deploying, it cant be found.

Is there a proper way if any, to do something like:

```
const utils = require('./libs/utils.js');
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    ...
    utils.do_this();
```

Trying this brings me to:

```
{"Message":"Cannot find module './libs/utils.js'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN5be18c53f5acf0299a224607fdeccedb.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Cannot find module './libs/utils.js'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN5be18c53f5acf0299a224607fdeccedb.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\n- /...
```

Answer (score 4):

Swimming deep in Twilio's doc swamp, I noticed there is [a hint on how to do this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/client?code-sample=code-load-a-module-from-an-asset&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default).

Basically you MUST

1. Add the .js file as an PRIVATE ASSET <- IMPORTANT! *unprotected wont work!
   i.e. if your file name is `utils.js`, rename it to `utils.private.js`
2. Get the path of that asset in the following way:

```js
// notice you don't need to write .private.
const path = Runtime.getAssets()['/utils.js'].path;
```

3. Require the path inside the handler:

```
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
     const path = Runtime.getAssets()['/utils.js'].path; 
     const utils = require(path);
```

Comment: Glad you found that in the docs. You can actually do this with either a private asset or a private function, depending how you want to store your code. Note that the `.private.` in file names is a convention used by the [Serverless Toolkit](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/serverless-toolkit) which is why `.private.` is not used in the name of the file returned by `Runtime.getAssets()`.

Comment: Please, for the love of god, add this to your documentation. (unless I missed it somewhere) to be clear, this getAssets/Functions part with respect to typescript compiled code. @philnash

Comment: Are you having trouble with this @CybeX? Or have you figured it out for now?

Comment: @philnash Figured out, as in converted (TS -> JS) and unified TwiML app into individual functions. Not the solution I was hoping for. I understand the architecture behind it, after looking into it more, would surely hope Typescript or atleast module support would be made available soon.

Comment: I am looking forward to module support too! Will try to get our recommended method of doing this documented soon.

Comment: Although it works, too bad that this way you'll miss code editing functionality, such as code completion on VSCode.

Comment: @ElvisFernandes No kidding, right? I have been trying for a couple days to get just that–first with Typescript, then with JSDoc and Typescript definitions (but vanilla JS source code). No matter what I try, it seems I can either have IDE support *OR* my Twilio functions can...function. Never both at the same time. It's really disappointing. Don't know whether to blame Twilio or Node or something else, but what a mess! If you generate a brand-new template TypeScript project w/Twilio's instructions and change nothing...it doesn't run! The documentation is a sprawl, too.